# ¿Cómo calculo la suma de una columna de mi tabla?

Tags: php, html, tablas, sum, sumatoria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como calculo la suma de la columna precio en mi tabla para obtener el total

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">


    <title>Lista de productos</title>

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }

        .table {
            border: none;
        }
        td{
            text-align: center;
        }
        h2 {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        h4{
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
        .data  td{
            text-align: center;
        }
        .info td{
            text-align: right;
           
            padding: 5px;

        }
        .info{
            padding: 5px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .stripped tr:nth-child(odd){
            background-color: #eee;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
   
    <table width="100%">
        <tbody width="100%">
            <tr width="100%">
                <td width="50%"> <img src="{{ $img }}" width="150px" height="130px"> </td>
                <td width="50%">
                    <h2>
                        SUBASTAS BUENAVISTA
                    </h2>
                    <h2>{{$subasta->name}} - {{ $subasta->end_date }} </h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  
    <table width="100%" >
        <tr>
            <td width="33%" style="vertical-align:top">
                <h3>PRODUCTOS</h3>
                <h4> {{ count($data) }}</h4>
            </td>
            <td width="33%" style="vertical-align:top">
                <h3>VENDIDOS</h3>
                <h4>{{ $vendidos}}</h4>
            </td>
            <td width="33%" style="vertical-align:top">
                <h3>NO VENDIDOS</h3>
                <h4>{{$noVendidos}}</h4>
            </td>
             <td width="33%" style="vertical-align:top">
                <h3>TOTAL</h3>
                <h4></h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   <br> 
    <table width="100%" class="stripped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td width="5%" style="text-align: center;"><b>No</b></td>
                <td width="15%" style="text-align: center;"><b>NOMBRE</b></td>
                <td width="15%" style="text-align: center;"><b>VENDEDOR</b></td>
                <td width="15%" style="text-align: center;"><b>ESTADO</b></td>
                <td width="15%" style="text-align: center;"><b>PRECIO</b></td>
                <td width="15%" style="text-align: center;"><b>COMPRADOR</b></td>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {{$subtotal = 0; }}
        @foreach($data as $i)
        <tr class="data">
            <td width="5%">{{ $i['product']->number }}</td>
            <td width="15%">{{  $i['product']->name }}</td>
            <td width="15%">{{ $i['product']->s_name}}</td>
            <td width="15%"> 
                @if( $i['product']->status == 1)
                    {{'No Vendido'}}
                @elseif( $i['product']->status == 0)
                    {{'Vendido'}}
                @else
                    {{'No vendido'}}

                @endif
            </td>
            <td width="15%"> 
                @if( $i['product']->status == 0)
                    {{ '$'.number_format($i['buyer']->price,2) }}
                @else
                    {{ 'NA' }}
                @endif
            </td>
            <td width="15%"> 
                @if( $i['product']->status == 0)
                    {{  "#".$i['buyer']->number.' - ' .$i['buyer']->name }}
                @else
                    {{ 'NA' }}
                @endif
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      
    </table>
</body>

</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">


    <title>Lista de productos</title>

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }

        .table {
            border: none;
        }
        td{
            text-align: center;
        }
        h2 {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        h4{
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
        .data  td{
            text-align: center;
        }
        .info td{
            text-align: right;
           
            padding: 5px;

        }
        .info{
            padding: 5px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .stripped tr:nth-child(odd){
            background-color: #eee;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
   
    <table width="100%">
        <tbody width="100%">
            <tr width="100%">
                <td width="50%"> <img src="{{ $img }}" width="150px" height="130px"> </td>
                <td width="50%">
                    <h2>
                        SUBASTAS BUENAVISTA
                    </h2>
                    <h2>{{$subasta->name}} - {{ $subasta->end_date }} </h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  
    <table width="100%" >
        <tr>
            <td width="33%" style="vertical-align:top">
                <h3>PRODUCTOS</h3>
                <h4> {{ count($data) }}</h4>
            </td>
            <td width="33%" style="vertical-align:top">
                <h3>VENDIDOS</h3>
                <h4>{{ $vendidos}}</h4>
            </td>
            <td width="33%" style="vertical-align:top">
                <h3>NO VENDIDOS</h3>
                <h4>{{$noVendidos}}</h4>
            </td>
             <td width="33%" style="vertical-align:top">
                <h3>TOTAL</h3>
                <h4>{{$vendidos}}</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   <br> 
    <table width="100%" class="stripped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td width="5%" style="text-align: center;"><b>No</b></td>
                <td width="15%" style="text-align: center;"><b>NOMBRE</b></td>
                <td width="15%" style="text-align: center;"><b>VENDEDOR</b></td>
                <td width="15%" style="text-align: center;"><b>ESTADO</b></td>
                <td width="15%" style="text-align: center;"><b>PRECIO</b></td>
                <td width="15%" style="text-align: center;"><b>COMPRADOR</b></td>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {{$subtotal = 0; }}
        @foreach($data as $i)
        <tr class="data">
            <td width="5%">{{ $i['product']->number }}</td>
            <td width="15%">{{  $i['product']->name }}</td>
            <td width="15%">{{ $i['product']->s_name}}</td>
            <td width="15%"> 
                @if( $i['product']->status == 1)
                    {{'No Vendido'}}
                @elseif( $i['product']->status == 0)
                    {{'Vendido'}}
                @else
                    {{'No vendido'}}

                @endif
            </td>
            <td width="15%"> 
                @if( $i['product']->status == 0)
                    {{ '$'.number_format($i['buyer']->price,2) }}
                @else
                    {{ 'NA' }}
                @endif
            </td>
            <td width="15%"> 
                @if( $i['product']->status == 0)
                    {{  "#".$i['buyer']->number.' - ' .$i['buyer']->name }}
                @else
                    {{ 'NA' }}
                @endif
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      
    </table>
</body>
```

Lo que quiero es sumar todos los valores de una columna precio y poder mostrarlos donde dice total.
[![quiero el total de todo lo de la columna tabla][2]][2]
Ahí esta la imagen, quiero el resultado de la columna PRECIO, quisiera saber como sumar todos los datos de una columna de mi base de datos.

Desconozco el código que tengo que poner ¿Cómo debería escribir el código?
Sé que para la mayoría será muy fácil mi pregunta, estoy aprendiendo :) gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Para sumar todos los valores de una columna en una base de datos, se puede utilizar una función de agregación como `SUM()`. La sintaxis para sumar todos los valores de una columna específica (por ejemplo, la columna "PRECIO") sería la siguiente:

```
SELECT SUM(PRECIO) AS Total
FROM nombre_de_la_tabla;
```

Donde "nombre_de_la_tabla" es el nombre de la tabla en su base de datos que contiene la columna "PRECIO". La función `SUM()` sumará todos los valores en la columna "PRECIO" y los devolverá como un único resultado con el alias "Total".

Comment: ok pero en que parte agrego eso?